# OpenCV VideoWriter writes an empty video

Tags: opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
import io

sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')


img = np.zeros((640,480))

center_x = 0
center_y = 256

videoFile1 = 'D:/Python/6. Const_Speed/sample1.mp4'

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('SaveVideo2.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

while True:
    img = np.zeros((640, 480))
    img = cv2.circle(img, (center_x, center_y), 20, 120, -1)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    out.write(img)

    center_x += 3
    time.sleep(1/30)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would like to record a video of a circle moving constant speed from left side of the screen to the right. The code above runs without an error, but the result video is empty with only black screen.

**What I tried**

1. I found that the video doesn't write if the dimension is different. So I matched the dimension to be (640,480)
2. I tried to change the codec from XVID to different codecs. At last, I found that 'XVID' codec works with .avi file, so I decided to keep it.

Comment: Why did you define `videoFile1` variable?

Comment: @Ahx I changed it when I was debugging. originally the first variable of VideoWriter was videoFile1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three-issues with your code.

**Issue#1**:

---

- If you are going to create `.avi`, I suggest you to use `MJPG`.

  - fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')

**Issue#2**:

- You need to define `VideoWriter` class carefully

  - When you are defining size, it should be `frame_width` and `frame_height`
  - For instance, if you want to create a video with the size `(640, 480)`, you need to initialize `VideoWriter` with `(480, 640)`
  - ```py
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('SaveVideo2.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (480, 640))
    ```
  - Also, you are planning to create a gray-scale video, therefore you need to initialize `isColor` to `False`
  - ```py
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('SaveVideo2.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (480, 640), isColor=False)
    ```

**Issue#3:**

---

- If you are creating a black image, you need to define its type:

  - ```py
    while True:
        img = np.zeros((640, 480), dtype=np.uint8)
    ```

If you fix the issues, result will be:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
import io

sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding='utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding='utf-8')


img = np.zeros((640, 480))

center_x = 0
center_y = 256

videoFile1 = 'video.mp4'

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('SaveVideo2.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (480, 640), isColor=False)

while True:
    img = np.zeros((640, 480), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.circle(img, (center_x, center_y), 20, 120, -1)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    out.write(img)

    center_x += 3
    time.sleep(1/30)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```